# How to trigger when a key is let up in as3 using a "keys" object?

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, keyboard, keyboard-events

The project I am currently working on is a top-down view tile-based video game, similar to the original Zelda game.

There is a bug that occurs if the player presses an arrow key and lets go of it in the middle of the walking animation. It stops on whatever frame of the animation it is currently on, causing the player to look like it is standing on one leg when not moving, which looks really goofy. I think this can be fixed by setting the sprNum of the character to the original number for the direction when the key is let up. BUT i have no idea how to do this.(Another bug is that if you stop in the middle of the walking animation and then continue in the same direction, it stays on whatever frame you stopped on and looks as if it floats around, which i think is being caused by the same thing).
In the game, i use the arrow keys to move the player around the screen, and the keys when pressed tell the character what direction to go, what direction to face, and to play a walking animation when moving.

This is done by creating a "keys" object and then adding the arrow keys into the object.

In the constructor i call the prepareGame function, and in that is the following.

```
keys = new Object();
//fill the object with arrow keys
keys[Keyboard.UP] = {down :false, dirx:0, diry:-1, sprNum:1, anim:[1,5,5,5,1,5,9,5]};
keys[Keyboard.DOWN] = {down:false, dirx:0, diry:1, sprNum:0, anim:[0,5,4,5,0,5,8,5]};
keys[Keyboard.LEFT] = {down:false, dirx:-1, diry:0, sprNum:3, anim:[3,5,7,5,3,5,11,5]};
keys[Keyboard.RIGHT] = {down:false, dirx:1, diry:0, sprNum:2, anim:[2,5,6,5,2,5,10,5]};
myParent.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downKeys);
myParent.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upKeys);
```

Here are the upKeys and downKeys functions.

```
//this function will detect keys that are being pressed
    private function downKeys (ev:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {
        //check if the is arrow key
        if (keys[ev.keyCode] != undefined) 
        {
            //set the key to true
            keys[ev.keyCode].down = true;
        }
    }
    //this function will detect keys that are being released
    private function upKeys (ev:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {
        //check if the is arrow key
        if (keys[ev.keyCode] != undefined) 
        {
            //set the key to false

            keys[ev.keyCode].down = false;


        }
    }
```

How can i detect when an arrow key becomes un-pressed? I need to do so so i can set the players sprNum to what ever direction it is facing, on the first frame of the walking animation so it looks like it is standing up.

Any help is greatly appreciated:)

EDIT:
Here is all the code that deals with the animation of the player.

In the hero class.

```
            public var anim:Array;
    public var animCount:int;
    public var animTime:int;
            public var sprNum:Number;


    public function Hero(spr:Number, tileSize:int, xt:int, yt:int) 
    {
        // constructor code
        sprNum = spr;
        sheet = new HeroSheet(0,0);
        ts = tileSize;
        anim = new Array();
        animCount = 0;
        animTime = 0;
        dist = 0;
        xtile = xt;
        ytile = yt;
    }
```

In the TBG Engine class, this is in the prepare game function.

```
animatedObjects = new Array();
hero = new Hero(0, 24, 2, 1);
animatedObjects.push(hero);
```

Here is the every frame function, with the movement being handled and that triggering the hero movement.

```
var moveOb:Object = new Object();
        //find if any movement key is down
        for each (var keyOb in keys) 
        {
            //yep, arrow key is down
            if (keyOb.down == true) 
            {
                //check if tile is walkable
                if (getMyCorners(hero.x + keyOb.dirx * hero.speed, hero.y + keyOb.diry * hero.speed, hero) == true) {
                    moveOb = keyOb;
                }else
                {
                    //we have hit the wall, place near it
                    if(keyOb.dirx < 0)
                    {
                        hero.x = hero.xtile * ts;
                    }else if(keyOb.dirx > 0)
                    {
                        hero.xtile = Math.floor((hero.x + hero.speed) / ts);
                        hero.x = (hero.xtile + 1) * ts - hero.ts;
                    }else if(keyOb.diry < 0)
                    {
                        hero.y = hero.ytile * ts;
                    }else if(keyOb.diry > 0)
                    {
                        hero.ytile = Math.floor((hero.y + hero.speed) / ts);
                        hero.y = (hero.ytile + 1) * ts - hero.ts;
                    }
                    moveOb.dirx = 0;
                    moveOb.diry = 0;
                    moveOb.sprNum = keyOb.sprNum;
                    moveOb.anim = [];
                    //try to move hero around the wall tiles
                    if(keyOb.dirx != 0)
                    {
                        var ytc:int = Math.floor((hero.y + hero.ts/2) / ts);
                        if(isWalkable(hero.xtile + keyOb.dirx, ytc)){
                            //align vertically
                            var centerY:int = ytc * ts + (ts - hero.ts) / 2;
                            if(hero.y > centerY)
                            {
                                //move up
                                hero.y--;
                                moveOb.anim = keyOb.anim;
                            }else if(hero.y < centerY)
                            {
                                //move down
                                hero.y++;
                                moveOb.anim = keyOb.anim;
                            }
                        }
                    }else
                    {
                        var xtc:int = Math.floor((hero.x + hero.ts/2) / ts);
                        if(isWalkable(xtc, hero.ytile + keyOb.diry))
                        {
                            //align horisontal
                            var centerX:int = xtc * ts + (ts - hero.ts) / 2;
                            if(hero.x > centerX)
                            {
                                //move left
                                hero.x--;
                                moveOb.anim = keyOb.anim;
                            }else if(hero.x < centerX)
                            {
                                hero.x++;
                                moveOb.anim = keyOb.anim;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if(moveOb.dirx != null)
        {
            //move the hero
            moveObject (hero, moveOb);
        }else
        {
            hero.anim = [];
        }
        //animate the objects
            animateSprite ();
```

And finally here is the animateSprite function.

```
private function animateSprite ():void 
    {
        //run through all objects needing the animation
        for (var n:int = 0; n < animatedObjects.length; n++) 
        {
            var ob:Object = animatedObjects[n];
            if(ob.anim.length > 0)
            {
                //add 1 to time counter
                ob.animTime++;
                var reachedEnd:Boolean = false;
                //check if the time has counted up
                if(ob.animTime == ob.anim[ob.animCount + 1])
                {
                    //add to current image counter
                    ob.animCount += 2;
                    //check if end of animation is reached
                    if(ob.animCount == ob.anim.length)
                    {
                        //reset to start
                        ob.animCount = 0;
                    }
                    //check if its tile or separate object like hero
                    if(ob.bmp == null)
                    {
                        //clear the current tile image
                        var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(ob.xt * ts, ob.yt * ts, ts, ts);
                        tilesBmp.bitmapData.fillRect (rect, 0x00000000);
                        //change the image if time is right
                        ob.s = ob.anim[ob.animCount];
                        drawTile (ob.baseSpr, ob.xt, ob.yt);
                        drawTile (ob.s, ob.xt, ob.yt);

                    }else
                    {
                        //its hero
                        ob.sprNum = ob.anim[ob.animCount];
                        ob.bmp.bitmapData = getImageFromSheet (ob.sprNum, ob).bitmapData;
                    }
                    //reset animation timer
                    ob.animTime = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2:
I added the suggested to the code below, but it still does the same thing:(

```
var moveOb:Object = new Object();
        //find if any movement key is down
        for each (var keyOb in keys) 
        {
            if(keyOb.down == false)
            {
                moveOb.anim = [keyOb.anim[1]]; 
            }
            //yep, arrow key is down
            if (keyOb.down == true) 
            {
                //check if tile is walkable
                if (getMyCorners(hero.x + keyOb.dirx * hero.speed, hero.y + keyOb.diry * hero.speed, hero) == true) {
                    moveOb = keyOb;
                }else
                {
                    //we have hit the wall, place near it
                    if(keyOb.dirx < 0)
                    {
                        hero.x = hero.xtile * ts;
                    }else if(keyOb.dirx > 0)
                    {
                        hero.xtile = Math.floor((hero.x + hero.speed) / ts);
                        hero.x = (hero.xtile + 1) * ts - hero.ts;
                    }else if(keyOb.diry < 0)
                    {
                        hero.y = hero.ytile * ts;
                    }else if(keyOb.diry > 0)
                    {
                        hero.ytile = Math.floor((hero.y + hero.speed) / ts);
                        hero.y = (hero.ytile + 1) * ts - hero.ts;
                    }
                    moveOb.dirx = 0;
                    moveOb.diry = 0;
                    moveOb.sprNum = keyOb.sprNum;
                    moveOb.anim = [];
                    //try to move hero around the wall tiles
                    if(keyOb.dirx != 0)
                    {
                        var ytc:int = Math.floor((hero.y + hero.ts/2) / ts);
                        if(isWalkable(hero.xtile + keyOb.dirx, ytc)){
                            //align vertically
                            var centerY:int = ytc * ts + (ts - hero.ts) / 2;
                            if(hero.y > centerY)
                            {
                                //move up
                                hero.y--;
                                moveOb.anim = keyOb.anim;
                            }else if(hero.y < centerY)
                            {
                                //move down
                                hero.y++;
                                moveOb.anim = keyOb.anim;
                            }
                        }
                    }else
                    {
                        var xtc:int = Math.floor((hero.x + hero.ts/2) / ts);
                        if(isWalkable(xtc, hero.ytile + keyOb.diry))
                        {
                            //align horisontal
                            var centerX:int = xtc * ts + (ts - hero.ts) / 2;
                            if(hero.x > centerX)
                            {
                                //move left
                                hero.x--;
                                moveOb.anim = keyOb.anim;
                            }else if(hero.x < centerX)
                            {
                                hero.x++;
                                moveOb.anim = keyOb.anim;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

        }
        if(moveOb.dirx != null)
        {
            //move the hero
            moveObject (hero, moveOb);
        }else
        {
            hero.anim = [];
        }
        //animate the objects
            animateSprite ();
```

Comment: You have to store current direction somewhere once the player starts moving, then you recall that at the time the player lets go of the direction key. I see you store the direction in `down` properties of your objects - good. Make sure that if your character can move diagonally, you don't make the animation stop if some keys are still pressed. Also, the animation code is where the bug is, not the declaration code. Please post animating code by editing your question.

Comment: I edited the above to add the animation code. Still very confused on how to fix the bug. @Vesper

Answer (score 0):

in the update function inside the for loop `for each (var keyOb in keys)` put another condition:

```
if (keyOb.down == false) { moveOb.anim = [keyObj.anim[0]]; }
```

but you should separate the movement code from the animation code, it will prevent  lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: I added the above but it is still doing the same thing, check the original question again, i edited it to show what i tried.